# iOS Swift - Show Contacts in TableView using UILocalizedIndexedCollation

Tags: ios, swift

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
    print("titleForHeaderInSection: \(collation.sectionTitles[section])")
    return collation.sectionTitles[section]
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String] {
    print("sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: \(collation.sectionIndexTitles)")
    return collation.sectionIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    print("sectionForSectionIndexTitle: \(sections.count)")
    return collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.results.count > 0) ? self.results.count : 0
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation().sectionTitles.count
    print("numberOfSections: \(numberOfSections)")
    return numberOfSections
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactscell") as UITableViewCell!
    let label             =   cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
    label?.text           =   self.results[indexPath.row].givenName
    return cell
}
```

It Display all contacts in every sections. I want to show contacts in sorted order with alphabetical index a to z

Answer (score 0):

You're returning self.results.count in numberOfRowsInSection regardless of which section you are in. You have to return the number of rows for each letter. Consider using a dictionary with letters as the keys and contacts as the values.